# ffmpeg: how to retag colour_range also on colour_range_Source=container (not only in the the stream)

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am working on an existing archive for a foundation (+1000h of video) the videos are encoded in h264
but  "colour_range" is erroneously flagged as "Limited"

Excerpt of media info output

> "colour_description_present": "Yes",
> "colour_description_present_Source": "Container / Stream",
> "colour_range": "Limited", "colour_range_Source": "Container /
> Stream", "colour_primaries": "BT.601 PAL", "colour_primaries_Source":
> "Container / Stream", "transfer_characteristics": "BT.601",
> "transfer_characteristics_Source": "Container / Stream",
> "matrix_coefficients": "BT.470 System B/G",
> "matrix_coefficients_Source": "Container / Stream",

i need to re-flag the video to full range, if i do :

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -metadata Video:colour_range=full -bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=1 output.mp4
```

i get only the stream reflaged but not the container

Excerpt of media info output

> "colour_description_present": "Yes",
> "colour_description_present_Source": "Container / Stream",
> "colour_range": "Limited", "colour_range_Source": "Container",
> "colour_range_Original": "Full", "colour_range_Original_Source":
> "Stream", "colour_primaries": "BT.601 PAL", "colour_primaries_Source":
> "Container / Stream", "transfer_characteristics": "BT.601",
> "transfer_characteristics_Source": "Container / Stream",
> "matrix_coefficients": "BT.470 System B/G",
> "matrix_coefficients_Source": "Container / Stream",

Chrome apparently is taking in account the only stream flag but firefox or vlc do not.

I can't find in the documentation how to reflag the colour_range in the container without re-encoding the video stream. If I use `-vf “setparams=range:full” -c:v copy` i get an error.

Any idea if it is possible? thanks